# How to system.web.mvc.mvchtmlstring convert to System.IConvertible in DropDownList?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, class, model-view-controller

> System.InvalidCastException: 'you can't convert object type
>   'System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString' into 'System.IConvertible'.'

That message shows when I tried to run my code, help pls

My Partial View

```
@model IEnumerable<SistemaDeAdminCasosJuridicos_Presentacion.Models.TipoCaso>

<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12" id="cbo">
        <label>Seleccionar tipo de Caso</label>
        @{
            List<SelectListItem> listItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
            foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Text).ToString(),
                    Value = @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Value).ToString(),
                    Selected = Convert.ToBoolean(Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Selected))
                });
            }
            Html.DropDownList("idTipoCaso", listItems, "Nombre");
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

My Jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('change', '#cbo', function () {
        var idTipoCaso = $(this).val();
        alert(idTipoCaso);
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Parametros/Tareas",
            cache: false
        }).done(function () {
            $("#divtareas").append('@Html.Partial("../Parametros/Tareas", Model.'+idTipoCaso+')');
        });
    });
});
```

My Controller

```
    // GET: Parametros/Tareas
    public ActionResult Tareas(int idTipoCaso)
    {            
        return View(Data.Data.ObtenerListaTareas(idTipoCaso));
    }
    // GET: Parametros/TipoCasos
    public ActionResult TipoCasos()
    {
        return View(Data.Data.ObtenerListaTipoCasos());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
@{
    List<SelectListItem> listItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Text).ToString(),
            Value = @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Value).ToString(),
            Selected = Convert.ToBoolean(Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Selected))
        });
    }
    Html.DropDownList("idTipoCaso", listItems, "Nombre");
}
```

with:

```
@{
    List<SelectListItem> listItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = item.Text,
            Value = item.Value,
            Selected = item.Selected
        });
    }
}
@Html.DropDownList("idTipoCaso", listItems, "Nombre");
```

`@Html.DisplayFor` returns `MvcHtmlString` that represents html. It is not what you need here. For `SelectListItem.Text` you only need `string` value of `item.Text`. The same is for `SelectListItem.Value`. Exception is thrown at `Convert.ToBoolean(Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Selected))`. `ToBoolean` method tries to convert given `MvcHtmlString` and since it is not what the method expect and it doesn't implement `IConvertible` it throws the exception.

Your div is empty since `Html.DropDownList("idTipoCaso", listItems, "Nombre");` returns `MvcHtmlString` to nowhere. You must place it outside of @{...} block, directly to html.

Comment: Thanks, it works, but now im getting nothing inside my div, its literally empty @AlbertK, i think my Html.DropDownlist is not working :(

Comment: is there any difference betwen use dropdownlist and a typical select option?

Comment: dropdownlist renders to the select element.You can render the select tag by yourself with a more granular control